# css transition stopped working

Tags: html, css

After changing styles to some inner divs hover transition stopped working. To see if that was the cause, i removed new styling, but the problem stayed. Can't understand why.

Live link is here

#### .com/

It's these blocks on the left of the slider

html code (though it's the same with the one that was working just fine before)

```
<div class="slidersidehover slidersideheight" id="sliderside1">
  <div id="sliderside1title"></div>  
  <div id="sliderside1content"></div>
</div>
  
<a href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="slidersidehover slidersideheight" id="sliderside2">
    <p id="sliderside2txt"></p>
  <div id="sliderside2bg"></div>  
  </div></a>
  
<a href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="slidersidehover slidersideheight" id="sliderside3">
    <p id="sliderside3txt"></p>
  <div id="sliderside3bg"></div>  
  </div></a>
```

and css

```
.slidersidehover {

background-color:black !important;
transition:0.3s;
-ms-transition:0.3s;
-o-transition:0.3s;
-moz-transition:0.3s;
-webkit-transition:0.3s;
}

.slidersidehover:hover {
opacity:0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to remove html comment `<!--slider-->`  in your style.css
and use css comment: `/* slider */`

Answer (score -2):

As far as I understand transitions only happen if you declare the property on both the active state and rest state.

```
.slidersidehover {
opacity:1;

background-color:black !important;
transition:0.3s;
-ms-transition:0.3s;
-o-transition:0.3s;
-moz-transition:0.3s;
-webkit-transition:0.3s;
}

.slidersidehover:hover {
opacity:0.5;
transition:0.3s;
-ms-transition:0.3s;
-o-transition:0.3s;
-moz-transition:0.3s;
-webkit-transition:0.3s;
}
```

I am not sure exactly what  effect you are going for but for explanation purposes I set the opacity to 1 on the rest state and then opacity to 0.5 on your hover. That should fix the issue.

Comment: Pls inform yourself more, this forum is not for guessing. The default value of opacity is 1 therefor this can't be the problem.